# How to fix slider.js for wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, slick.js

I am trying to create a Slick JS with ACF repeater, but it doesn't work.

The following code just shows image after image.

Is there something I have forgotten?

By the way, I have already registered the CSS and JavaSscript's on `functions.php`.

```
<section>
    <div id="slick-hero">

        <a id="slick-hero-left" class="slick-hero__arrow-container slick-hero__arrow-container--prev">
          <div class="slick-hero__icon-container">
            <div class="slick-hero__icon">
              <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>

        <a id="slick-hero-right" class="slick-hero__arrow-container slick-hero__arrow-container--next">
          <div class="slick-hero__icon-container">
            <div class="slick-hero__icon">
              <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>

      <div class="slick-hero__slider">
        <?php if ( have_rows( 'slider_2019_home' ) ) : ?>
        <?php while ( have_rows( 'slider_2019_home' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
        <div class="slick-hero__slide" style="background-image:url(<?php the_sub_field('slider_home_2019_image'); ?>)">
          <div class="container slick-hero__slide__container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="slick-hero__slide__content">
                <a class="slick-hero__slide__link" href="<?php the_sub_field('slider_home_2019_link'); ?>">
                  <h4 class="slick-hero__slide__heading">
                    <?php the_sub_field('slider_home_2019_heading'); ?>
                  </h4>
                  <h2 class="slick-hero__slide__title">
                    <?php the_sub_field('slider_home_2019_sub_title'); ?>
                  </h2>
                  <hr class="hero-slider__divider">
                  <p class="slick-hero__slide__body">
                    <?php the_sub_field('slider_home_2019_body'); ?>
                  </p>
                  <p class="slick-hero__slide__cta-text">
                    <?php the_sub_field('slider_home_2019_cta_text'); ?>
                  </p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
      <?php else : ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
      </div> <?php // end slick-hero__slider ?>
    </div> <?php // end slick-hero ?>
</section>
```

Comment: update question with software versions.

Comment: Can you replicate the problem in jsfiddle? Can you confirm that your javascript file has enqueued successfully? Are you getting any JavaScript errors in your console?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slick-hero__slider").slick()
})
```

anywhere?

Comment: ```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slick-hero__slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll:1,
    prevArrow: $('#slick-hero-left'),
    nextArrow: $('#slick-hero-right'),
    dots: true
  });

Comment: $('.slick-hotel__slider').slick({
    dots: true,
    arrows: true,
    rows: 2,
    slidesPerRow: 3,
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 992,
        settings: {
          rows: 2,
          slidesPerRow: 2,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          autoplay: true,
          autoplaySpeed: 1000,
          speed: 1000,
          slidesPerRow: 1,
          rows: 1,
        }
      }
    ]
  });

  $('.slick-dots').addClass("container");

});